# Whose gas is consumed for indirect contract's function call?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

i'm working on solidity for Dapp dev.

Let me assume this situation below, with 2 contracts, `A` and `B`.

```
contract A {
    B contract_b;
    constructor(address b_addr) {
        contract_b = B(b_addr);
    }

    function pass() public {
        contract_b.do_sth();
    }
}
```

```
contract B {
    constructor(address b_addr) {
        //
    }

    function do_sth() external {
        // do something state-changing stuffs //
    }
}
```

I vaguely noticed that view function does not spend gas,

so if `do_sth()` is `view` function, then nothings' bothering.

but with debugging, i found that in processing `do_sth()` invoked by `pass()`,

`msg.sender` becomes the **constact address of A**, **not the original sender**.

which means, in `do_sth()` scope, `msg.sender` is changed.

Then, whose gas will be consumed for `do_sth()` process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Ethereum transaction has a gas attached to it and only this gas can be spent during the processing of the transaction. Any contract calls count against the original transaction and contracts cannot pay the gas fee themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it means "msg.sender" is changed, but "msg.gasleft()" is indirected to the other contract? seems tricky but understandable..

Comment: `gasleft` is also changed, because the calling contract may explicitly set a limit of the allowed gas for the call. This is to protect against some vulnerabilities (forcing a contract revert even though contract thinks it has gas left).

Comment: @SeongjoonPark you can also still access the orignal msg.sender with tx.origin